# Simplified Bash getopts flow

Tags: bash, console, meta-programming

I've always found the boilerplate needed to use [`getopts`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-getopts) correctly fairly fiddly and verbose, and was motivated to try to abstract it away. I wanted to try dynamically writing the parsed arguments into `local` variables accessible to the calling function, and I came up with this:

```
main() {
  local _usage='foo [-a] [-b] [-f val] [-v val] [args ...]'
  eval "$(parse_opts 'f:v:ab')"
  echo "f=$f v=$v a=$a b=$b -- $#: $*"
}

main "$@"
```

Yes, it uses `eval`, but given the alternative (a crufty `while` loop and `case` statement), I think it's still an improvement.

I'm looking for any general feedback about this approach and implementation. Can I reduce the amount of code being `eval`ed? Anything I can simplify or improve? Any edge cases or bugs I've missed?

Relevant code/docs:

```
# Helper utility to simplify using Bash's getopts utility, and make it
# usable with functions.
#
# Example usage:
# foo() {
#   local _usage=...               # optional usage string
#   eval "$(parse_opts 'f:v:ab')"  # provide a standard getopts string
#   echo "f is $f"                 # opts are now local variables
#   if (( a )); then               # check boolean flags with (( ... ))
#     echo "Saw -a"
#   fi
# }
#
# This script eliminates the gruntwork and verbosity of using getopts,
# allowing you to focus on actual behavior rather than argument parsing.
# It handles looping over getopts, parsing each result, and reporting
# errors. Each parsed option is set as a local variable in the calling
# function, enabling easy and safe access to all values.
#
# No-arg options are set to 0 by default and 1 if passed as an
# argument, allowing concise testing with (( ... )).
#
# Options that accept an argument are set to the empty string by
# default, and otherwise set to the value passed as an argument.
# To check if a (non-empty) argument was passed use [[ -n "$..." ]].
#
# All parsed arguments are shift-ed out of $@, leaving any
# subsequent positional arguments in-place. A -- argument can be
# used to halt option parsing early, e.g. `-a -- -b` will only
# parse -a and leave -b as an argument.
#
# Parsing errors cause the calling function to return with exit
# code 2. If a _usage variable is set before argument parsing
# its contents will be included in the error message.
#


# Actual parser implementation; assumes all variables it sets
# are local, which parse_opts sets up. Do not call directly.
_parse_opts_helper() {
  local OPTARG opt optstring=${1:?optstring}; shift
  # ensure string _is_ prefixed with :
  while getopts ":${optstring#:}" opt; do
    case "${opt}" in
      [?:])
        case "${opt}" in
          :) echo "Option '-${OPTARG}' requires an argument" >&2 ;;
          [?]) echo "Unknown option '-${OPTARG}'" >&2 ;;
        esac
        if [[ -n "$_usage" ]]; then
          echo "Usage: $_usage" >&2
        fi
        return 2
        ;;
      *)
        if [[ "$optstring" != *"${opt}:"* ]]; then
          OPTARG=1
        fi
        printf -v "$opt" '%s' "$OPTARG"
        ;;
    esac
  done
}

# The output of this function is intended to be passed to eval,
# therefore we try to minimize what it prints and delegate most
# of the heavy lifting to a separate function.
# Expected output:
#   local OPTIND=1 a b c=0 # vars are dynamically parsed
#   _parse_opts_helper a:b:c "$@" || return
#   shift $((OPTIND - 1))
#   OPTIND=1
parse_opts() {
  local i char last_char vars=() optstring=${1:?optstring}
  optstring="${optstring#:}" # ensure string is not prefixed with :
  if ! [[ "$optstring" =~ ^[a-zA-Z:]*$ ]] || [[ "$optstring" == *::* ]]; then
    echo "Invalid optstring: $optstring" >&2
    return 2
  fi
  for (( i=${#optstring}-1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )); do
    char=${optstring:i:1}
    if [[ "$char" != ":" ]]; then
      if [[ "$last_char" == ":" ]]; then
        vars+=("$char")
      else
        vars+=("${char}=0")
      fi
    fi
    last_char=$char
  done
  echo "local OPTIND=1 ${vars[*]}"
  printf '_parse_opts_helper %q "$@" || return\n' "$optstring"
  echo 'shift $((OPTIND - 1))'
  echo 'OPTIND=1'
}
```

Pulled from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dimo414/93776b78a38791ed1bd1bad082d08009) which will likely be kept more up-to-date than the code pasted here.